# Sequence converging to $0$ a.e. on $[0,1]$ but the integral does not go to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I need a sequence of nonnegative measurable functions, $\{f_k\}$, defined on $[0,1]$ such that

$$f_k \rightarrow 0$$

a.e. on $[0,1]$ but the integral over $[0,1]$ doesn't go to $0$. So I thought of

$$f_k(x) = xe^{-k}$$

if $x \in (0,1)$ and $0$ otherwise.

and

$$f_k(x)=x^k$$

for $x \in (0,1)$ and $0$ otherwise. However both of their integrals tends to $0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$. Any hints? I wanna say my function need not be bounded as if it were bounded, then the integral would also converge to $0$, correct?

Comment: Think about a sequence of step functions that have shrinking support but growing height.

Comment: So by shrinking in support could I consider the characteristic function $\chi_{[\frac{k}{k+1},1]}$ or $\chi_{[0, \frac{1}{k}]}$ @CameronWilliams as $k$ goes from $1$ to $\infty$? Probably the latter one.

Comment: Yep! Now modify the height so that the integral doesn't go to $0$.

Comment: Take $f_{n}=n\mathbf{1}_{\{(0,\frac{1}{n})\}}$

Comment: Was just gonna say can I just multiply by $k$? @CameronWilliams

Comment: You can do it with continuous functions, and with $f_k(x)\to 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: @HossienS'MyMathYourMath' Yep. Great work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:- Take $f_{n}=n\mathbf{1}_{(0,\frac{1}{n})}$

Then $\int_{[0,1]}f_{n}\,d\lambda \to 1 $ but $f_{n}\to 0$ pointwise.

Comment: shouldn't I take $f_n= n \chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$?

Comment: You can. In that case you will get a.e. convergence as $f_{n}(0)=n$ will diverge . But in this case you get pointwise. What I am trying to say is that even pointwise convergence is not enough to guarantee convergence in $L^{1}$. So it does not make too much of a difference anyway as you only want a.e. convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possibility with all the $f_k$ continuous. Make $f_k$ continuous and piecewise linear, with graph passing through $(0,0), (\frac1k,0),(\frac2k,k),(\frac3k,0),(1,0)$.

The integral of each $f_k$ is $1$, but pointwise, $f_k\to 0$

Comment: How on earth did you come up with this lol

Comment: @HossienS'MyMathYourMath' I had some college professors who drilled this sort of example into me...quite some time ago I might add, so they must have done a good job since it came back to me!